# R - Applying formula through partitioning a dataset

Tags: r, bing-maps, geo, data-partitioning

I need to use Bing maps API to get co-ordinate data for a list of pincodes (India). I can do this for small datasets with the code:

```
get_lat_long <- function(pincodes) {
  # key: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Application
  require(XML); require(data.table)
  PinCodeLatLong <- data.frame(pincode = "Temp", lat = "Lat", long = "Long")
  for(i in 1:length(pincodes)){ 
    var = pincodes[i] 
    link=paste0("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?postalCode=",var,"&o=xml&maxResults=1&key=<mykey>") 
    #data<- xmlParse(link) 
    xml_data <- xmlToList(xmlParse(link)) 
    PinCodeLatLongtemp <- data.frame(pincode = "Temp", lat = "Lat", long = "Long") 
    PinCodeLatLongtemp$pincode <- var
    PinCodeLatLongtemp$lat <- xml_data$ResourceSets$ResourceSet$Resources$Location$Point$Latitude 
    PinCodeLatLongtemp$long <- xml_data$ResourceSets$ResourceSet$Resources$Location$Point$Longitude 
    PinCodeLatLong <- rbindlist(list(PinCodeLatLongtemp,PinCodeLatLong), fill = T) 
  }
  return(PinCodeLatLong)
}
master_lat_long <- get_lat_long(pincode_map$Pincode)
master_lat_long <- dplyr::filter(master_lat_long, !is.na(pincode))
master_lat_long <- master_lat_long[!duplicated(master_lat_long),]
pincode_map <- merge(pincode_map, master_lat_long, by.x="Pincode", by.y="pincode", all.y=FALSE)
```

However, Bing Maps Basic API only allows for 2500 datapoints at a time and I need to do this for a large dataset (100,000+). What would be the best way to partition and apply the formula to the file master_lat_long? Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways you can split the data for every 2500 values.

One way with `ceiling` would be :

```
result <- by(pincode_map$Pincode, 
             ceiling(seq_len(nrow(pincode_map))/2500), get_lat_long)
```

Comment: ```Error in tapply(seq_len(19144L), list(`ceiling(seq_len(nrow(pincode_map)/2500))` = c(1,  : 
  arguments must have same length```
getting this error on trying this with a 19144 rows dataset

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my previous code. Can you try the updated code?

Comment: It is now working. However, still couldn't get the Maps API to work correctly (still throws the same HTTP resource error). I will have to look into it tomorrow again as the daily quota is likely over by now.

Comment: I don't know what `get_lat_long` function does and how it is supposed to work. My code divides `Pincode` into chunks of 2500 and passes it to `get_lat_long`. If `get_lat_long` works for any 10 or so values the above code should work as well.

Comment: It is working, but I am still getting some error (no data available for some pincodes). I need to get some error handling codes in there. Thank you.